# Pandas and Fuzzy Match

Tags: pandas, fuzzywuzzy

Currently I have two data frames. I am trying to get a fuzzy match of client names using fuzzywuzzy's process.extractOne function. When I have run the following script on sample data I get good results and no error, but when I run the following on my current data frames I get both an Attribute and Type error. I am not able to provide the data for security reasons, but if anyone can figure out why I am getting errors based on the script provided I would be much obliged.

```
names2 = list(dftr3['Common Name'])
names3 = dict(zip(names2,names2))
def get_fuzz_match(row):
            match = process.extractOne(row['CLIENT_NAME'],choices = n3.keys(),score_cutoff = 80)
            if match:
                return n3[match[0]]
            return np.nan    
 dfmi4['Match Name'] = dfmi4.apply(get_fuzz_match, axis=1)
```

I know not having some examples makes this more difficult to troubleshoot, so I will answer any question and edit the post to help this process along. The specific errors are:

1.AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'items'

2.TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 1):

The AttributeError is straightforward and to be expected, I think. Fuzzywuzzy's `process.extract` function, which does most of the actual work in `process.extractOne`, uses a `try:... except:` clause to determine whether to process the `choices` parameter as dict-like or list-like. I think you are seeing the exception because the TypeError is raised during the `except:` clause.

The TypeError is trickier to pin down, but I suspect it occurs somewhere in the `StringProcessor` class, used in the `processor` module, again called by `extract`, which uses several string methods and doesn't catch exceptions. So it seems likely that your `apply` call is passing something that is not a string. Is it possible that you have any empty cells?